# What to do with ground wire downstream from ungrounded GFCI?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, gfci, grounding

I am replacing an ungrounded receptacle with a GFCI receptacle, and I will be adding two new receptacles downstream from the GFCI receptacle.

In another post, someone had quoted from one of the code books, which said "An equipment grounding conductor shall not be connected from the ground-fault circuit-interrupter-type receptacle to any outlet supplied from the ground-fault circuit-interrupter receptacle".

I take this to mean that the grounding wires in the new cables between the GFCI receptacle and the other two receptacles are not to be connected to anything. So what do we do with the ends of the grounding wire? Put some tape on the ends in the boxes? Clip it short? Stick a wire connector on each end? Any inputs are appreciated!

For clarify, the attached image shows the layout of the circuit.

[image]

Comment: Newer code allows you to run a separate ground(a bare wire) from a good ground to a device(receptacle/GFCI).  This might be easy for you or a big PITA, but might be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Code doesn't specify, I would just tuck into the back of the box so it would be available to connect if further renovation made access to a ground available.

The Code requires affixing a label to the covers stating 'No Equipment Ground".  One reason the code requires the label is [NEC 250.114](https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#250.114) requires certain appliances and tool to only be connected to properly grounded receptacles. The instructions included with appliances or tools requiring a ground will also instruct to plug into a grounded receptacle, instructions included with Lab Listing (UL/CSA/ETL) are part of the Listing.

If you need to use one of the receptacles for EGC required items you will need to find a route to ground the circuit.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - thanks! Part of my concern was if there was some sort of risk I was unaware of to having an unattached ground in the box; nothing I reviewed specifically made note of what to do with it. I'll likely just coil it with a needle-nose and tuck it safely in the back.    And yes - I am aware of the labelling requirement, and that will be addressed using the labels provided with the GFCI receptacle.